# When exactly are declarativeNetRequest rules applied?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I'm currently trying to figure out when exactly chrome applies the `declarativeNetRequest` rules, specifically `HeaderOperation.REMOVE`.

For testing this, I'm using the following setup:

**Extension A** that (using `webRequests`) logs all headers received:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    (details) => {
      console.log(`Headers for ${details.url}:`);
      details.responseHeaders.forEach(header => {
        console.log(`${header.name}: ${header.value}`);
      });
    },
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ["responseHeaders"]
  );
```

Extension B that (using `declarativeNetRequest`) removes some headers:

```js
const allResourceTypes = Object.values(chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType);

const rules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    priority: 1,
    action: {
      type: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType.MODIFY_HEADERS,
      responseHeaders: [
        {
          operation: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.HeaderOperation.REMOVE,
          header: 'header-name',
          
        },
      ]
    },
    condition: {
      urlFilter: "|http*://*/*",
      resourceTypes: allResourceTypes,
    }
  }
];

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  removeRuleIds: rules.map((rule) => rule.id), // remove existing rules
  addRules: rules
});
```

Now I would expect this to remove all headers of type `header-name` (and this header to not be logged by Extension A).

What I'm getting however, are two somewhat contradictory results:

- When using [Testheaders](https://testheaders.com), the headers seem to be removed successfully (I tested it with `cf-ray`, which is a header returned by cloudflare).
- Extension A however, still prints out those headers.

Does this mean that, even when headers are removed by an extension, other extensions are still always able to see all of the original headers?

I'm looking for an answer on what the intended behaviour would be, as well as the relevant part of the documentation.

Comment: It may be a bug because DNR should apply before webRequest, but on the other hand maybe this order is guaranteed only within one extension, whereas for multiple extensions they see the requests in the order of installation.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm! I just tested this by checking the behaviour in both cases (A installed before B, B installed before A), and it does not change anything.
Would you happen to have any documentation / sources about when which rules are applied? To me it seems like Extension A always receives all the headers. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: It may be a bug, so it's best to report in https://crbug.com.

Comment: For future reference, here is the bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1516619